# A control not contributing to the size of its container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

This is somewhat hard to explain, but I'll try my best.
I currently have a grid with two columns and several rows.
I only want the controls in the second column to contribute to the height of the grid.

So, in the following example, I would want the listbox to be the height of the two textblocks and show a scrollbar if it needed to show more data. I am drawing a blank on how i could do this.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this?  Scrollviews don't have a predefined size so I would expect the grid to conform to the size of the controls in the second column.

Comment: You probably don't want to use columns since I don't think you can auto size them that way without hacking it with procedural code.  You probably want to use grids inside a grid, or stack panels.  I can't say how you should do it without knowing the requirements--how many list boxes do you expect to have, only 1 ever?  How many text blocks do you expect to have, only 2?  Or do you have 1 listbox and 2 text blocks per each composite item and you have to stack the items in rows?

Comment: @mydogisbox - I have tried this, and it didn't work for me.

Comment: What exactly did you try and what didn't work as you desired?

Comment: @Moozhe - I want this to be a generic solution so the items in the columns shouldn't matter. You can always wrap everything in the first column in another grid anyways.

Comment: @mydogisbox - Basically, I don't want the first column to ever affect the height of the `Grid`. I gave an example because people on SO like examples, but it really isn't need in this case. In the example, if the listbox grows too much, it will also increase the height of the grid.

Comment: I think I understand what is happening now.  Grids expand to fill any available space, so if your grid isn't competing with any other controls for space it will simply occupy as much space as any contained item asks for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind nasty hacks:

```
<FrameworkElement Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Name="Hax" />
<ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"
         Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Hax}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew that I could do this and it does work. However, as you mentioned, its not the prettiest of things to do. I was hoping for something better.

Comment: @BryanWatts: How about implementing a control by overriding `Measure` and `Arrange` respectively?

Comment: I think you're right @H.B.  Probably the only clean way to do it.

Comment: @H.B. - I wouldn't mind creating my own control, it just seemed like overkill for such a simple design request. I'm unfamiliar with `Measure` and `Arrange`. I assume they are methods on `FrameworkElement`? I will look into it.

Comment: @BryanWatts: Just a warning, this *might* be impossible because you get limited information in those methods. You will want to take as much space as dictated by the other controls, however at the point where the measurement happens they probably have not done so and each child is evaluated independently. If this is the case you would need to tackle it at the root: Subclass Grid and copy & modify it's measure and arrange, you could then create a new attached property, like `GridEx.AffectsLayout` to get the no-space information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks right now like the grid is stretching to fill IT's parent.  Try setting the outer Grid's height to Auto and VerticalAlignment to top:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ListBox Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That should not change anything, the ListBox is still dictating the height.

Comment: Really, the Grid's VerticalAlignment could be anything EXCEPT Stretch.

Comment: That doesn't fix my problem. I agree with @H.B., it doesn't change the fact that if the `ListBox` grows, then the grid will grow.

Comment: No, the ListBox isn't driving the height (other than affecting the MINIMUM height of the containing grid), by default it is stretching to fill its parent.  Height defaults to Auto, VerticalAlignment defaults to stretch.  Try setting the Height of the TextBlocks and notice that the ListBox will stretch.